# Activity Diagrams created in Visio 2013 (Preview)?

Tags: diagram, visio, activity-diagram

In the past I was using Rational Rose, and now I'm trying to switch to Visio. But many things that I could easily find in Rose, I can't or have hard time finding it in Visio (2013 Preview).

I have looked at the available diagram possibilities (when creating a new file) but I could not decide what to choose, what would be the best for making Activity Diagrams.

Please tell me.
What would be the best choice? How should I start?

Answer (score 1):

For activity diagrams, Click on More Shapes, then on Software and Databases, in Softare category, choose UML Activity.

Comment: I think he means some parts are missing. For starters, there don't seem to be any sub-activities to be available.